# php loop start over when num_rows==0

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a php code to select form tables:

1. books
2. images

Some books does not have an image, so I want to skip it and select another book.
I have wrote this code but it does not work with me perfectly.

Now I'm getting only 5 records! it must be 6 as I limited in the book select query.

```
$slider_sql = "select * from books  limit 6";
$slider_result = $conn->query($slider_sql);
while($slider_row = $slider_result->fetch_assoc()) {
   extract($slider_row);

   $img_sql = "SELECT big_img FROM images WHERE book_id = '$id'";
   $img_rs = $conn->query($img_sql);
   $img_row = $img_rs->fetch_assoc();

   if ($img_rs->num_rows == 0) 
       continue; //--> here I want to start while again to select another book.
    echo $book_name.'<br>';
    echo $img_row['big_img'].'<br>';
}
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: This is pretty old school, I'd suggest using PHP PDO object with a simple foreach loop.  Best of luck!

Comment: @Machavity, extract probably sets $id.

Comment: @AaronBelchamber What? Old school...?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: A `LIMIT 6` means that it will return *as many as* 6 records, but you're not guaranteed to get exactly 6.

Comment: @tadman I'm guessing that OP is' getting 5 rows because of the `continue;`  where one of the books doesn't have an image. You're right though, if there's just 5 rows in the dataset, it's hard to get 6 different ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a sub-query in a loop (which is nearly ALWAYS a bad idea!), use a `JOIN` instead, which simplifies it to one query instead of two. Then set a condition that `big_img` should not be empty. This guarantees that you will only find rows where there's an image matching the book. `LIMIT` will still only ensure the return of 6 rows. `<>` in MySQL is the same as `!=`.

```
$slider_sql = "SELECT b.book_name, i.big_img 
               FROM books b 
               JOIN images i 
                 ON i.book_id=b.id 
               WHERE i.big_img <> '' 
               LIMIT 6";
$result = $conn->query($slider_sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['book_name'].'<br>';
    echo $row['big_img'].'<br>';
}
```

- [MySQL `JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Fantastic, I just added GROUP BY i.book_id because some books has many images. Well done @Qirel